# How do I use CurrentCharacter in matlab?

Tags: matlab, keyboard, character

I am trying to use the CurrentCharacter property in matlab but I don't know how it works. Could somebody give me an example? I have tried to use `get(gcf,'CurrentCharacter');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MATLAB documentation:

> ```
> CurrentCharacter
> ```
>
> single character
>
> Last key pressed. MATLAB sets this property to the last key pressed in
>   the figure window. Use CurrentCharacter to obtain user input.

I'm not sure how you're intending to use it, but here's a simple way to demonstrate it;;

1. Create a figure
2. Click on the figure (bring it to front in the OS GUI)
3. Type a character (it will likely appear in your command window)
4. Enter `kkey = get(gcf,'CurrentCharacter')` in your command window

By doing this you set `kkey` to the first character you typed while your figure window was active.

Comment: how can i reset this value?, i am using it in a condition like if kkey=='s' do something. So i really need to reset this value to any other char after the condition.

Answer (score 4):

Run this code and start pressing the keys on the keyboard. Observe the output on the Command Window.

```
f = figure;
set(f, 'KeyPressFcn', @(x,y)disp(get(f,'CurrentCharacter')))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Syntax is very simple:

```
fig = figure(300);
try
    key_press=waitforbuttonpress;
catch 
    disp("Figure closed sorry");
    keyId = 27;
    return;
end
keyId=double(get(fig, 'CurrentCharacter'));
```

Where keyId=id of key that you have been pressed. For example:

```
27  is Esc

28  is <-

29  is ->*
```